# How to communicate between controllers of two different modules in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs

I want to know that can we communicate between two different controllers in AngularJS. Suppose  I have Two modules,
Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/if0MQwlx9WHrD8XnMi2t?p=preview

```
    1. var app = angular.module('fistModule', []);
           app.controller('first', function ($scope) {
                $scope.firstMethod= function () {
                 //my code}
} )
    2. var newapp = angular.module('secondModule,[]');
           newapp.controller('second', function ($scope) {
              $scope.secondMethod= function () {
               //my code}
```

Is there way to communicate between controllers of two different modules.

My Code:
JS:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('ParentCtrl', ['$scope',
    function($scope) {

      $scope.message = "Child updated from parent controller";

      $scope.clickFunction = function() {
        $scope.$broadcast('update_parent_controller', $scope.message);
      };
    }
  ]);
  angular.module('myNewApp', [])
  .controller('ChildCtrl', ['$scope',
    function($scope) {
      $scope.message = "Some text in child controller";

      $scope.$on("update_parent_controller", function(event, message) {
        $scope.message = message;
      });
    }
  ])
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="ParentCtrl">

    <div ng-app="myNewApp" ng-controller="ChildCtrl">
      <p>{{message}}</p>
    </div>

    <button ng-click="clickFunction()">Click</button>
  </div>
```

Comment: Whether they're in the same module or not doesn't change anything.

Comment: this mean I can communicate between controllers using $broadcast.

Comment: Yes, no problem doing that.

Comment: @JBNizet can you create an example for this. please..

Comment: How about you doing that, and asking a question if you don't succeed?

Comment: I am getting an error when I am using $broadcast to pass the data.

Comment: same code is working fine if, both controllers are in same module..

Comment: Then post the complete code, the stack trace of the error, and create a plunkr that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Ok.. I am doing this..

Comment: I have updated the question with plunker link.

Comment: Communication between controllers using broadcast/emit is considered a bad practice. You should be using services. As well, using parent-child scopes to communicate brings strong-coupling between controllers and is very error prone. Use services for communication between controllers.

Answer (score 5):

As @JB Nizet says, you do it the exact same way. You use a `service` to communicate between two controllers.

One module needs to have the other module as a dependency. This is always a one-way dependency. I have made `secondModule` a dependency of `firstModule`.

As well, the `value` in the service is stored in an object called `data`. This is because JavaScript does not pass values by reference -- but does pass objects by reference. So this is a form of `boxing`.

```js
angular.module('firstModule', ['secondModule'])
  .controller('FirstController', FirstController)
  .service('sharedData', SharedData);

FirstController.$inject = ['sharedData'];
function FirstController(sharedData) {
  
  this.data = sharedData.data;
}

function SharedData() {

  this.data = {
    value: 'default value'
  }

}

angular.module('secondModule', [])
  .controller('SecondController', SecondController);

SecondController.$inject = ['sharedData'];
function SecondController(sharedData) {
  
  this.data = sharedData.data;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="firstModule">

  <div ng-controller="FirstController as vm">
    First Controller in module firstModule<br>
    <input type=text ng-model="vm.data.value" />
  </div>

  <div ng-controller="SecondController as vm">
    Second Controller in module secondModule<br>
    {{vm.data.value}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

your plunker has a very minor issue.

change this

```
     angular.module('myApp', [])
```

to

```
     angular.module('myApp', ['myNewApp'])
```

Comment: It has another issue: it tries using ngApp twice. @ng_developer: read the documentation of ngApp: *Only one AngularJS application can be auto-bootstrapped per HTML document. The first ngApp found in the document will be used to define the root element to auto-bootstrap as an application*.