# Sharing data between two directives (but not part of the same module)

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have the following situation:

I have my app (module "zmApp") which has a directive, "myDirective"
I am also using a 3rd party angular directive, lets call it "thirdPartyDirective", which is defined under "thirdPartyModule" by that author.

What I now want to do is share some data between 'myDirective' which is part of "zmApp" and "thirdPartyDirective" which is defined under "thirdPartyModule"

I tried creating a factory in zmApp and injecting it into "thirdPartyDirective", but that throws an error "Reference not found". I suspect its because they are two different modules.

I know directives can also have controllers, but my guess is if factories did not work nor will  controllers.

How do I solve this predicament?

Many thanks

Comment: Share between the isolate scopes

Comment: You can share data between directives with a service/factory. If it wasn't working you would get an `Error: $injector:unpr
Unknown Provider` not an error saying "Reference not found"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27720707/how-to-communicate-between-controllers-of-two-different-modules-in-angularjs/27721056#27721056 take a look at this. It is communication between two controllers in separate modules. Same concept applies.

Comment: @AR7, you are absolutely correct. I was pulling my hair out on this - as it turned out, i injected it into one directive and was using from another directive in the same file without knowing it was part of another directive.  I don't see any way to accept a comment, so I upvoted it.

Comment: @user1361529 lol just like your avatar. Glad I could help